# How to count decision tree rules in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, decision-tree, rpart, supervised-learning

I employed RPart to build a decision tree. Without a problem, I am doing this. But, I need to learn (or count) how many times the tree has been splitted? I mean, how many rules (if-else statement) the tree has?
For instance:

```
                  X
                 - - 
        if (a<9)-   - if(a>=9)
               Y     H
              -
      if(b>2)- 
            Z
```

There are 3 rules.

When I write summary(model):

> summary(model_dt)

```
Call:
rpart(formula = Alert ~ ., data = train)
  n= 18576811 

         CP nsplit  rel error     xerror         xstd
1 0.9597394      0 1.00000000 1.00000000 0.0012360956
2 0.0100000      1 0.04026061 0.05290522 0.0002890205

Variable importance
         ip.src frame.protocols   tcp.flags.ack tcp.flags.reset       frame.len 
             20              17              17              17              16 
         ip.ttl 
        `    12 

Node number 1: 18576811 observations,    complexity param=0.9597394
  predicted class=yes  expected loss=0.034032  P(node) =1
    class counts: 632206 1.79446e+07
   probabilities: 0.034 0.966 
  left son=2 (627091 obs) right son=3 (17949720 obs)
  Primary splits:
      ip.src          splits as LLLLLLLRRRLLRR ............ LLRLRLRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR
    improve=1170831.0, (0 missing)

      ip.dts splits as  LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRLLLLLLLLLLL, improve=1013082.0, (0 missing)
      tcp.flags.ctl   < 1.5   to the right, improve=1007953.0, (2645 missing)
      tcp.flags.syn < 1.5   to the right, improve=1007953.0, (2645 missing)
      frame.len       < 68    to the right, improve= 972871.3, (30 missing)
  Surrogate splits:
      frame.protocols splits as  LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRLLLLLLLLLLL, agree=0.995, adj=0.841, (0 split)
      tcp.flags.ack   < 1.5   to the right, agree=0.994, adj=0.836, (0 split)
      tcp.flags.reset < 1.5   to the right, agree=0.994, adj=0.836, (0 split)
      frame.len       < 68    to the right, agree=0.994, adj=0.809, (0 split)
      ip.ttl          < 230.5 to the right, agree=0.987, adj=0.612, (0 split)

Node number 2: 627091 observations
  predicted class=no   expected loss=0.01621615  P(node) =0.03375666
    class counts: 616922 10169
   probabilities: 0.984 0.016 

Node number 3: 17949720 observations
  predicted class=yes  expected loss=0.0008514896  P(node) =0.9662433
    class counts: 15284 1.79344e+07
   probabilities: 0.001 0.999
```

If anyone helps me to understand it, I will be grateful

SIncerely
Eray

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, through some knowledge of how the tree object (`?rpart.object`) is returned.

I'll show two ways using the `kyphosis` data set in R following the first example in `?rpart`:

```
fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis)
```

#### Option 1

```
> tail(fit$cptable[, "nsplit"], 1)
3 
4
> unname(tail(fit$cptable[, "nsplit"], 1)) ## or
[1] 4
```

From the `cptable`, which contains information on the cost complexity of trees of a given size

```
> fit$cptable
          CP nsplit rel error   xerror      xstd
1 0.17647059      0 1.0000000 1.000000 0.2155872
2 0.01960784      1 0.8235294 1.176471 0.2282908
3 0.01000000      4 0.7647059 1.176471 0.2282908
```

From what I recall, the last line of this table will refer to the current largest tree. If you prune the tree to a particular size based on CP, the last line of this matrix will contain the information on the tree of this size:

```
> fit2 <- prune(fit, cp = 0.02)
> fit2$cptable
         CP nsplit rel error   xerror      xstd
1 0.1764706      0 1.0000000 1.000000 0.2155872
2 0.0200000      1 0.8235294 1.176471 0.2282908
```

#### Option 2

A second option is to count the occurrence of `<leaf>` in the `var` column of the `frame` component of the fitted model:

```
> fit$frame
      var  n wt dev yval complexity ncompete nsurrogate    yval2.V1    yval2.V2
1   Start 81 81  17    1 0.17647059        2          1  1.00000000 64.00000000
2   Start 62 62   6    1 0.01960784        2          2  1.00000000 56.00000000
4  <leaf> 29 29   0    1 0.01000000        0          0  1.00000000 29.00000000
5     Age 33 33   6    1 0.01960784        2          2  1.00000000 27.00000000
10 <leaf> 12 12   0    1 0.01000000        0          0  1.00000000 12.00000000
11    Age 21 21   6    1 0.01960784        2          0  1.00000000 15.00000000
22 <leaf> 14 14   2    1 0.01000000        0          0  1.00000000 12.00000000
23 <leaf>  7  7   3    2 0.01000000        0          0  2.00000000  3.00000000
3  <leaf> 19 19   8    2 0.01000000        0          0  2.00000000  8.00000000
      yval2.V3    yval2.V4    yval2.V5 yval2.nodeprob
1  17.00000000  0.79012346  0.20987654     1.00000000
2   6.00000000  0.90322581  0.09677419     0.76543210
4   0.00000000  1.00000000  0.00000000     0.35802469
5   6.00000000  0.81818182  0.18181818     0.40740741
10  0.00000000  1.00000000  0.00000000     0.14814815
11  6.00000000  0.71428571  0.28571429     0.25925926
22  2.00000000  0.85714286  0.14285714     0.17283951
23  4.00000000  0.42857143  0.57142857     0.08641975
3  11.00000000  0.42105263  0.57894737     0.23456790
```

This value - 1 is the number of splits. To do the counting we can use:

```
> grepl("^<leaf>$", as.character(fit$frame$var))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
> sum(grepl("^<leaf>$", as.character(fit$frame$var))) - 1
[1] 4
```

The regular expression I use is probably overkill but it means check for a string starting with (`^`) and ending in (`$`) `"<leaf>"`, i.e. this is the *entire* string,. I use `grepl()` to return the matches on the `var` column as a logical vector, which we can sum up the `TRUE`s and subtract 1 from. As `var` is stored as a factor, I convert this to a character vector in the `grepl()` call.

You could also do this using `grep()` to return the indices of the matches and use `length()` to count them:

```
> grep("^<leaf>$", as.character(fit$frame$var))
[1] 3 5 7 8 9
> length(grep("^<leaf>$", as.character(fit$frame$var))) - 1
[1] 4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations!!

> sum(grepl("^<leaf>$", as.character(model_dt$frame$var))) - 1
[1] 1

so it means I have only one splitting rule?
if yes, then what is the meaning of, for example " ip.dts splits as  LLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLLRLLLLLLLLLLL" . I think there is 31 split rules for this part?

My dataset is more than 10GB, is it logical that I have only 1 split?

Comment: Type `fit` at the R prompt and it will show you how many splits you have. (where `fit` is the object containing your tree). That way you can check...

Comment: Hi I had a similar requirement where I want to select the CP value for pruning so that I get max 5 leaves only. Is there a way I can do such selection. Also how can I now the values that each of the leaves are satisfying. Actually I am using rpart trees to have groups of my categorical variable such that they are associated with my continuous variables. You inputs would help me a lot !! Thank you !!

Comment: I have posted my question and link to the same is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228786/rpart-find-number-of-leaves-that-a-cp-value-to-pruning-a-tree-would-return   it would help a lot if you can provide your suggestion to achieve this.