# rpart - Find number of leaves that a cp value to pruning a tree would return

Tags: r, tree, decision-tree, rpart, pruning

I have a requirement where I need to group my categorical variables (having more than 5 category values) into 5 groups based on their association with my continuous variable. To achieve this I am using **rpart** with "**annova**" method.

So for example my categorical variable is **type** having codes **1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15** so I want to have 5 groups of this variable. After running the tree inorder to have only 5 groups I need to prune the tree. One way I tried is to use the **nsplit** from **cptable** but, nsplit of 5 might give me 7-8 leaves and similarly **nsplit** of 4 might give me 5-6 leaves.

I was looking for an option by which when I prune I get only 5 leaves which would act as my 5 groups.

Can someone please suggest how I can achieve this by using rpart.

Thank you !!

Comment: perhaps use `hclust` and `cuttree` instead of `rpart`.

Comment: @missuse, I haven't used cuttree or hclust.....hclust I believe would create the groups but not sure if it would take in to consideration the association with my continuous variable.....could you please share an example which I can refer to?

Comment: You would calculate the distance among your points based on the numeric variable and then cut the tree to obtain 5 groups.